# CSS or jquery on background image over <img>

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to place a play button over an image that has a 3px border. When the user rolls over **the image** I want the **play button to :hover and also the image border to :hover**.

Problem is that the play button only engages when I roll over it. Not when I roll over the image.

My HTML:

```
<div class="views-field-field-thumbnail">
       <a href="/videos">
          <img src="individual.png" width="230" height="130">
       </a>
</div>

<div class="thumbnail-play">Play</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.views-field-field-thumbnail img {border: 7px solid #333;}

.views-field-field-thumbnail img:hover {border: 7px solid #000;}

.thumbnail-play {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: url(VideoPlayerOff.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-top: -95px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    }

.thumbnail-play:hover {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: url(VideoPlayerOn.png) 0px -50px no-repeat;
    }
```

**Update:** Looks like I can alter the code a bit and place the play image wherever I need it to be. Just a bit confused where its best placed.

Comment: I want the play button to engage when I roll over the image (not the play image, but the individual.png image). If I make the play button a block and extend it to the size of the image then I lose my link. Make sense?

Comment: maybe you will need some jquery for this, is jquery an option? or you have to change the markup :(

Comment: Either would work. I already have jquery running, but there has to be a CSS way. I don't mind changing the markup. The only thing I cant remove is the main image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery you just need to add this lines:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.views-field-field-thumbnail img, .thumbnail-play').hover(
      function(){
        $('.thumbnail-play').css('background', 'url(VideoPlayerOn.png) 0px -50px no-repeat');
    },function(){
        $('.thumbnail-play').css('background', 'url(VideoPlayerOff.png) 0px 0px no-repeat');
        }
    );
});
```

The css is the same, just delete the `.thumbnail-play:hover` style.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error on the 4th line: $('.thumbnail-play').css('background', 'url(VideoPlayerOn.png) 0px -50px no-repeat';

Comment: @Dan: I forgot to close the css function with `)`, check now. PD. You should be able to fix details like the parenthesis ;)

Comment: Tom thats close, but when you roll over the box, then the photo, it changes back. I'd want the image to stay rolled over till the cursor left the box.

Comment: Tom I don't know what to tell you. When I mouse over the large image, the small image changes. But then when I put my mouse over the small image, it changes back to the first image. I'd want it to stay on the 2nd image the whole time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your play image inside your `.views-field-field-thumbnail` div so you that can access it with `:hover`.

```
<div class="views-field-field-thumbnail">
    <a href="/videos">
       <img src="individual.png" width="230" height="130">
    </a>
    <div class="thumbnail-play">Play</div>
</div>


.views-field-field-thumbnail:hover img {border: 7px solid #000;}
.views-field-field-thumbnail:hover .thumbnail-play {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: url(VideoPlayerOn.png) 0px -50px no-repeat;
}
```

If you can't do this, I'm afraid you'll have to resort to javascript.

```
$('.views-field-field-thumbnail').hover(function()
{
   $(this).next('.thumbnail-play').addClass('hover');
},
function()
{
   $(this).next('.thumbnail-play').removeClass('hover');
});
```

and change `.thumbnail-play:hover` to `.thumbnail-play.hover` in your CSS.

Comment: Thanks @Plynx, but unfortunately I can't put it inside as my CMS (Drupal) is creating these <div>'s. I'll check out the javascript.

Comment: +1 Nice trick with the `...thumbnail:hover .thumbnail-play` selector.

Comment: @Plynx I was able to change the html like above and use CSS, but my VideoPlayerOn.png image shows up behind my main image. I can't get it in front.

Comment: @Dan it's probably a stacking conflict from somewhere else in your CSS. You can always try setting a `z-index:9999` or something on your `thumbnail-play` and see if that works before trying to debug your CSS.